# Memory compatibility

Tags: laptop, memory

A few years ago I bought a hp ProBook 6470b. It had decent specs, and looked pretty cool. I've been running Linux on the machine for quite a while now, and have started to notice some slowdowns. The laptop came with 4Gb which I think needs an upgrade. I found one ram stick (4Gb) online, [from Crucial](http://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/probook-6470b/CT3506032), and wonder if they will go along together, and if i need to consider anything else before buying.

Picture of the memory inside the computer.
[image]

Comment: I also found one on [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005LDLV6S/ref=psdc_172500_t1_B008L325TW?th=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them look ok to me (the ones from Amazon and Crucial). Everything seems to match up: Form Factor (sodimm), Speed 1600Mhz, Model No.

In conclusion, it looks to me like the RAM you looked at and the RAM that Esbjorn suggested ***are compatible***.